# Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) for arrow function expression vs normal function expression

Tags: javascript

```js
const log = function (x)
{
 console.log(x);
}
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(num=>log(num))
```

This throws error:-

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 13
}
```

Which is because of lack of semi-colon before the array. So it's misinterpreted as:-

```
const log = function (x)
{
    console.log(x);
}[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(num=>log(num))
```

But why does the following work:-

```js
const log = (x)=>{
 console.log(x)
}
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(num=>log(num))
```

I understand that it's also a function expression as well. Is there an exception for arrow function in ASI? Or am I missing something?

Comment: [ECMAScript® 2021 Language Specification -> 11.9.1 Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion) says:

> When, as the source text is parsed from left to right, a token (called the offending token) is encountered that is not allowed by any production of the grammar, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true: [...]

So for ASI to happen, the syntax may be an invalid production without it. And actually it is:

```
  () => {}[0] // syntax error
```

So the Semicolon is needed here. Now why is that a Syntax error, while `function () { }[0]` is not? Well, the member access is defined as

```
  MemberExpression:
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    PrimaryExpression
    //...

 PrimaryExpression:
   FunctionExpression
   // no arrow function here
```

Why the Syntax is how it is? I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about restricted productions :D. It only made sense that arrow functions were some sort of exception under a category and you pointed me to it.

Comment: actually this is not quite right, will edit (but can't delete as it is accepted)

Comment: Oh okay yeah please edit and let me know the correct picture of it.

Comment: So for normal function expression, function(){}[0] is not an invalid production according to ASI but arrow function expression is?

Comment: @lakshya yes `function() { }[0]` is valid syntax, while `() => { }[0]` is not. `(() => { })[0]` is however.